What is the meaning of this black/white (likely non-traffic) sign seen on German highways?
Often I saw this sign at highways in Germany:

Apparently it's not a regular traffic sign, but nevertheless I'm curious about its meaning. I tried to ask a local, but they also didn't know.

Tuxedo required

@CristobolPolychronopolis - This road sponsored by HSBC

These signs are part of a test track for autonomous driving.
The German Wikipedia says in its article about the A9:

Teststrecke für autonomes Fahren
Abschnitte [der A9] in Bayern sollen als Testfeld für Innovationen im Bereich autonomes Fahren und Assistenzsysteme dienen. Das Projekt Digitales Testfeld Autobahn wurde im September 2015 initiiert. Ende 2016 wurden zwischen Pfaffenhofen und Kreuz Holledau spezielle Landmarkenschilder aufgestellt. Diese runden Schilder mit schwarz-weißem Muster dienen der zentimetergenauen Positionsbestimmung durch Kamera-unterstützte Navigation. Insbesondere kann so die Positionsgenauigkeit im regulären Verkehr anhand unabhängiger Fixpunkte gemessen werden.

Translation (using DeepL):

Test track for autonomous driving
Sections [of the A9] in Bavaria are to serve as a testing ground for innovations in the field of autonomous driving and assistance systems. The Digital Test Field Motorway project was initiated in September 2015. At the end of 2016, special landmark signs were installed between Pfaffenhofen and the Holledau junction. These round signs with a black and white pattern are used to determine the position to the centimetre using camera-assisted navigation. In particular, the position accuracy in regular traffic can be measured using independent fixed points.


"determine the position to the centimetre" I know that German engineering is legendary, but ground moves. Unless the posts are set in concrete footers below the frost line, it'll only take one good winter for them to have frost-heaved more than a centimeter and be out of alignment. Of course, they're Germans, so they may well have put appropriate footings down...

@FreeMan I wouldn't put it beyond the engineers to have DIN norm for that.

@Peter - Reinstate Monica: http://ak-doerr.com/ivz-norm/

@FreeMan in Germany, the ground needs to fill out 4 different complicated official forms before it gets permission to move. Usually it doesn't bother. There, problem solved!

@FreeMan: I can find plenty of articles from various news outlets on these signs, and virtually all of them quote then minister of traffic Alexander Dobrindt as saying (translation by myself): "Autonomous cars (...) must exactly know their location at any moment. The special signs (...) are an important fixed point for this purpose. Together with modern sensors and maps exact to the centimetre (...)". While I could not yet find any specifics on how those signs work, it is at least conceivable that they do not have to be positioned exactly to the centimetre themselves, but that e.g. their ...

... location +/- 15 centimetres, combined with very exact map data, combined with some sensor information about the current surroundings of the vehicle is sufficient for exactly determining the location. Oh, and also, in the context of the quotation, "zentimetergenau" might be hyperbole that just means something like "down to a couple of centimetres", or even "more precise than metres".

I’d say quite the opposite is true. An autonomous car should reach its destination with inaccurate location data, and should be able to drive safely with no location data at all.

From my understanding: it's not meant for actually navigating, but for verifying whether the position derived by other measures is correct (as this is a "test track").

@gnasher729 You need the ability to work without the location data for a level 5 self drive.  AFIAK nobody's made any such cars, yet.  Stuff like Waymo is level 4--capable of safely dealing with anything it will encounter in a limited environment.  Safely, not necessarily correctly.  Safely might include stopping and waiting for human guidance.

@FreeMan as long as you know how much the post has moved, that doesn't matter. You can get your desired precision back.

@leftaroundabout, so now both the newly autonomous vehicle and the previously autonomous ground are draped/enfolded in regulatory officialdom some many layers deep.

I didn't know, @leftaroundabout, I didn't know...

@FreeMan: that's why similar marks are used to track how ground (or parts of buildings) move... or hopefully: don't
